# UINavigationController return nil Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, delegates, swift5

When i try `print(self.navigationController)` in `viewWillApear` or `viewDidLoad` all ok. But when delegate return response from API `print(self.navigationController)` return `nil`. What could it be?

```
extension EnterpriseList: APIDataDelegate {
    func successRequest() { //print(self.navigtionController) == nil
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }

    func badRequest() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Alert.showWarningAlert(withTitle: "Внимание!", andMessage: "Ошибка получения данных, попробуйте чуть позже", whereSender: self)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your code? 
You meant `print(self.navigationController)` not print(self.UINavigationController)

Where are you getting the delegate callback; in ViewController?

Comment: @Manoj ok, i did

Comment: @Manoj ```successRequest``` told me what ```UINavigationController``` is ```nil```

Comment: You are checking the value of `navigationController` in same `EnterpriseList` controller. Am I correct?

Comment: @Manoj yes. When i first time callback ```successRequest``` all ok, but second time my app just crash

Comment: I am writing code to see the reason for crash, till then can you share the crash report you see in console

Comment: @Manoj console is empty. I can find crash reason by printing and this all because ```slef.navigationController``` is ```nil```

Comment: I have added the answer below. Your `self` is nil and not the `navigationController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class EnterpriseList: UIViewController {
     let dataSource = DataSource()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataSource.delegate = self
        dataSource.makeAPICall()
     }
  }

   extension EnterpriseList: APIDataDelegate {
      func successRequest() {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
   }

   func badRequest() {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
      }
   }
}

protocol APIDataDelegate: class {
    func successRequest()
    func badRequest()
}

class DataSource {
    var delegate: APIDataDelegate?

    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Test", qos: .background, attributes: [], autoreleaseFrequency: .inherit, target: nil)

    func makeAPICall() {
        queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {[weak self] in
            self?.delegate?.successRequest()
        }
        queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {[weak self] in
            self?.delegate?.successRequest()
        }
    }
}
```

The crash is because you are calling the method on deallocated object.

Here is how to fix this:
Make your delegate is weak and you are correctly deallocating the objects

```
weak var delegate: APIDataDelegate?
```

Comment: now console told me what delegate is ```nil``` when i try callback delegate second time

Comment: Why do you need the delegate callback when your view is deallocated (i.e nil).
It does not make sense to get the callback after you pop your viewController

You need to explain and share your code more for me to understand what is needed

Answer (score 0):

Thx @Manoj for answers it's halped me. But i found solution in other. Besides `SurveyList` i have `UserMenu` where i create `static let` view controllers. Removing `static` i solved my problem.